# Why are events in Calendar View overflowing day boxes when printed/print previewed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, printing, layouts

I have an employee whose issue I've verified on my own machine who has recently (last two months or so) noticed that, when she tries to Print or Print Preview the Calendar view of a SharePoint Online list, said Calendar's events are not respecting the boundaries of the 'day' box. I've reproduced this issue on both Firefox 65 and IE11 on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Here's what the calendar looks like in the browser:

[image: calendar browser view]

And here is what it looks like when in Print Preview (and when actually printed):

[image: print preview w/ overflowing events]

As you can see, these (mostly) one-day events are showing up as boxes that spill over partially or completely into another day.

Why is this happening, and (how) can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't fix it. (and I'm getting the same result!)

It looks like a CSS issue where the display CSS and the print CSS (SharePoint has both) are out of sync after the most recent SharePoint Online update. These updates are quite frequent, and don't always seem to be fully tested.

I would go to your Office 365 Admin Portal and submit a Service Request. Give them as much detail as possible and hopefully they will get it fixed.

Comment: Luckily I am fairly adept with CSS, so I can fix this with a custom user style in a pinch, but it's good to know this has been confirmed outside of our organization so easily. For now I'll probably recommend the user sync their calendar with Outlook and print it from there (and of course submit a ticket to MS as well).